# Python threads and daemons

Tags: python, pthreads, daemon

I'm working with daemons in python using the [Sander's recipy](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/).

Till now has run fine, but I have to introduce some changes which are drilling my brain. 
The fact is:

The Sander's daemon way of life creates a new instance of the object everytime you ask for it. Example:

```
[prompt]> python my_daemon.py start
[prompt]> python my_daemon.py check_whatever (new instance of my_daemon.py is created, but it looks for pid and finally gets the first one.)
```

Then, looking for the pid used to create the older instance, you can access to it and manage with it.

The situation is: this daemon spawns two threads that continue working after the daemon has performed the start command and is ready for admit another one (remember, a new instance is created). I would like to access to this threads in another command but, I haven't found the way (if there's one).
As far as I researched, with the pid you can only kill or check the daemon, but don't know if is posible to get the objects (ergo, the threads) created by that instance.

**Open questions**:

-If I can recover the process from its pid, can I also access to its objects?

-Do I have to consider convert this threads to subprocess in order to keep them alive after, its main thread has finished (or is still waiting)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether a new process would be necessary per-se, but it would probably be a lot cleaner to implement than having to carefully manage your way around the GIL, depending on the size of the tasks the daemon's threads execute, and whether they are pure-python, or can release the GIL by calling a foreign library.

As for accessing by pid, I'm not sure whether that's possible, it definitely isn't for threads under windows as they do not have their own pid; it seems a lot more simple to me to keep a pipe open to your new threads.

There are really too many architecture decisions to answer this cleanly, but if you have made these decisions already, feel free to add more info to your question and I'll try and give a more informed answer.

Comment: I haven't chosen any decisions yet. I just simply found that using a process which spawns threads in the start command, I'm not able to access them in the rest of the commands.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a "purge" in the content of the code, reducing active lines to the minimum, I realized that threads stand still (as good warriors). There are some problems when I deal with files which I think can be founded in the behaviour of the daemon itself (because it sets file descriptors to null).

For now, I consider myself happy, cause I can use some dummy protocol to alter the running behaviour of those threads (for example a dummy config file).

Comment: How curious, not able to deal with files inside the run method of the Daemon (the overridden one in my own class).

Comment: [irony]Does the sentence os.chdir("/") says something to you?[/irony] I was missing this change. All files were been put int "/".